# Ajax call loads the current content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have looked through so many forums racking my brain to try and get this super simple load function working. I've narrowed it down to what I believe is a selector issue on the `.fadeIn()` part of the `loadContent` function.

I can see why it keeps loading the same stuff, as it uses the same selector, but based on the tutorial I've been trying to use (http://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/) as well as the other (even MORE broken) method that I DID get to work (based on this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery--net-26), it seems like it should work!

I've tried using `$(href)` as a selector, but then it just fades the old content and doesn't load anything. I also tried adding an alert to see what href was, and it returned the correct html page followed by the correct element id (Articles/Cats.html #content).

Here's the function itself, and if you need more info, I'd be glad to give it! Any help would be incredibly, well, helpful!

```
function articleClickLoad () {
    if (Modernizr.history) {

        var newHash      = "",
            $Content     = $("#content"),
            $el;

        $("#content").on("click", "a", function() {

            var _link = $(this).attr("href");
            var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';

            history.pushState(null, null, _link);
            loadContent(toLoad);
            return false;
        });

        function loadContent(href){

            $Content.find("#content");
            $Content.fadeOut(1000, function() {
                $("main").load(href,'', function() {
                    $Content.fadeIn(1000);
                });
            });
        }

        $(window).bind('popstate', function(){
           _link = location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''); //get filename only
           loadContent(toLoad);
        });
    }
}
articleClickLoad();
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're not loading any new data from anywhere, so where do you expect the new data to come from?

Comment: @Izzey `$("main").load(...)` is not loading data?

Comment: Well .load is calling href, which is the new page content, but I'm not really sure how to make that content fadeIn

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the load part.

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential issues. [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) takes a URL <strike>but you're adding `' #content'` in your click handler for some reason; it should be removed</strike> Update: I overlooked that passing a page fragment is perfectly valid, forget about that.

In your `loadContent` method, you're calling `load` on a selector `$("main")`. It is not clear from your source what `main` could be but I suppose it should be `#content` instead.

Also note that you can remove the second parameter `''` from the `.load` call. See [.load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: `$("main")` is the parent to `#content` in index.html, so I didn't want the loaded `#content` to be added as a child to the existing `#content`. the tutorial I was following (which worked great!) basically called `.load` with `_link + " #content"`, so I figured I could just put it into one variable, `toLoad`.

Comment: Just a note, when `$("main")` was originally `$Content`, I still had this same issue.

Comment: Alright then. I just recognized that .load('url #id') is perfectly valid, too. Sorry this wasn' of any help.

Comment: One more random shot: try `$('main #content').fadeIn(1000);` instead of `$Content.fadeIn(1000);`.

Comment: Sadly it did not work, but I appreciate the suggestion!